# Fileupload Control not working in Chrome but works in IE, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, sharepoint

The code is only works for IE because Chrome is just giving filename for file control, while IE is giving full path.
How to make it works with chrome too?
I'm uploading and overwrite an attachment in Sharepoint

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
         if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
              FileUpload fileUpload = row.Cells[0].FindControl("FileUploadControl") as FileUpload;

              if (fileUpload.HasFile)
              {
                   filePath = fileUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
                   GetUrl(filePath);
              }
         }
     }

     public void GetUrl(string filePath)
        { 
           SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http:/test/"))
               {
                 using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                 {
                   var fi = new FileInfo(filename);
                   var list1 = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Customer");
                   clientContext.Load(list1.RootFolder);
                   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                   var fileUrl = String.Format("{0}/Attachments/{1}/{2}", list1.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, ids, fi.Name);
                   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, fs, true);
                 }
               }
           });                
        }
```

Comment: Different browsers render them differently. Try using plain HTML file upload controls.

Comment: is there any other way to make it compatible with all browser? something like read the file instead of using full path to read the file or any other solution?